# choose any number e that is relatively prime to n

Tags: functions

I try to write a command that means choose any number e that is relatively prime to n, like
e^n [Congruent] 1 (mod n), but it didn't give me a value of e.
    e^n [Congruent] 1 (mod n)

Comment: There are an infinite number of numbers that are relatively prime to n (in the general case), so you must give more constraints for Mathematica to compute the number you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a one off answer, you can try

```
FindInstance[GCD[24, x] == 1, x, Integers]
```

This returns an integer x that is coprime to 24. If you want five such numbers:

```
FindInstance[GCD[24, x] == 1, x, Integers, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous, but if you're asking "find all elements of a list that are relatively prime to a chosen number n," then this will work (illustrated for n = 5):

```
Select[Range[30], CoprimeQ[5, #] &]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29}

You can multiply m by the product of 100 random prime numbers and add 1. That will give a large number relatively prime to m. Here:

```
m Times @@ RandomChoice[Prime /@ Range[50000], {100}] + 1
```

Comment: Hi, I'm asking that just choose one number e that is relatively prime to a known number n. How could I write the command? Thank you. And that know number n is huge big.

Comment: If you wanted "just one" number relatively prime to 5, would you accept 3?  4?  7?  94?  If so, you simply MUST give more constraints to yield "just one" such number.  A trivial "solution" for you would be given n, return n+1.

Comment: It's for setting up my own RSA scheme. I want to get a number e that  e is relatively prime to m which m is a known number. And I know e^(m)=1(mod m), but I don't know how to find the m.

Comment: m+1 satisfies your (poor) constraints.  Use that.

Comment: If it's for an encryption scheme that is for actual security, DON'T use that!  Generate a random integer, test if it is relatively prime, and if not, generate another random integer.  I'll provide an implementation in another answer.

Comment: My point exactly.  You simply MUST (but have not yet) provide a constraint upon the infinite number of integers that are relatively prime to m.  Until you do that, there is no principled answer to your question.  Is 2m+1 adequate?  If you want a random number, in what range will you accept it?  You really must specify your problem more carefully.

Comment: You can multiply m by the product of 100 random prime numbers and add 1.  That will give a large number relatively prime to m.  Here:  m Times @@ RandomChoice[Prime /@ Range[50000], {100}] + 1

Comment: @DavidG.Stork `RandomPrime[]`?

Comment: Yes.  RandomPrime[] is better.  Hence m Times@@RandomPrime[{1,10^5},{100}]+1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function `relPrime[n]`

```
relPrime[n_, numBits_: - 1] := Module[{
   e = n,
   bits = If[numBits != -1, numBits, (*naive guess for number of bits:*) 2 Log[2, n]]
   },
  While[! CoprimeQ[e, n], e = RandomInteger[2^bits]];
  Return[e];
  ]
```

which accepts a number `n` and an optional argument `numBits`.  If `numBits` is not provided, it assumes you want an integer less than `2^(2 Log[2,n])`.

eg.:

```
relPrime[7]      (* gave 43 *)
relPrime[7]      (* gave 8  *)
relPrime[7, 10]  (* gave 187 *)
relPrime[7, 10]  (* gave 531 *)
relPrime[7, 30]  (* gave 417815679 *)
relPrime[7, 30]  (* gave 69523772 *)
```

Of course, the output is (likely) to differ, since you're testing a random integer.

For real cryptographic purposes you should work over a finite field, where each integer has a nonzero likelihood of being picked.

Comment: Thanks, I used your command to choose it!